# Rails Belongs To Dependent Destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

What is the best way, to check that a model relationship is in use in another model to prevent it from being destroyed thus creating an orphan.

**Example:**  I have a Ticket and TicketStatus models.  TicketStatus belongs to Ticket.  Ticket has_many TicketStatuses.

I should not be able to delete a TicketStatus if it is already assigned to a Ticket.  I would like an error message as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest ways a callback:

```
class TicketStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ticket
  before_destroy :check_ticket

  private

  def check_ticket
    if ticket != nil
      errors.add_to_base("cannot delete ticket status that has a ticket")
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

This prevents it and gives you an error.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`before_destroy` callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html), and make sure to `return false`, which cancels the impending delete.